# React styling with variable classname

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, django

I am making a chat app and the message has a classname of the current user's username. And I want if a user send a message to appear in blue while if the other one send one to appear in red.

So I wanna do something like this:

```
{currentUser.username} {
    background:red
}
```

Comment: are you sure you want it in css, not in style attribute or as different classes?

Comment: seems like you would have a ternary when you are outputting it and not make dynamic css....

Comment: @epascarello I have thought of doing it with ternary but I can't figure it out in the coding. Also I don't care if it is style attribute.

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/applying-classes-conditionally-react

Answer (score 0):

I cant add a comment so i will put this here, in order to do it with ternary you can do something similar:

```
<div className={userId===desiredUserId?"classNameUser1":"classNameUser2"}></div>
```